# Numpy Boolean Indexing to match multiple values

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to use boolean indexing in numpy to create a boolean array corresponding to the existence of certain values in an array.

The obvious attempt I made was:

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

xBool = x == 2
xBool2 = x == 3
xBool3 = x == 5

x[xBool] = 0
x[xBool2] = 0
x[xBool3] = 0

print(x)
```

**-- Output --**

```
>>> 
[1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 4 0]
```

This is what I want, but as you can see from the code, it requires separate lines for each match. This can get very long for more than 3 comparisons.

I then tried the following:

```
y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

yBool = y in (2, 3, 5)

y[yBool] = 0

print(y)
```

However I got an error saying:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.

Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I am unsure how to make multiple comparisons in a quick way rather than using separate boolean arrays. Is there a sort of `OR` I can use for boolean indexing?

Comment: Use [`numpy.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.1/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html)?

Comment: @Divakar I didn't know about that. That might just work.

Comment: something like `(~np.isin(x, [2,3,5]))*x`